# Python Split Unless Next Character Is Something

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am using Python 3.5, and I would like to split a string by the character `\n`, or new line. however if the line starts with a underscore, for example, it should put that line with the one above it. I need the solution to work for all characters, not just underscore. It should work like this:

```
a = '''red
yellow
green
_surprise!
blue'''

print(a.split('\n')
```

and should result in:

```
['red', 'yellow', 'green\n_surprise', 'blue']
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't do this only using `str.split`. Either use the `re` module or just join the strings afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy using regular expressions:

```
import re
re.split('\n(?!_)', a)
# ['red', 'yellow', 'green\n_surprise!', 'blue']
```

This regex litterally means `split by \n not followed by _`.

Answer (score 0):

You can repalce `\n_` with some characters and then split the string with delimiter `\n`

```
>>> a = '''red
... yellow
... green
... _surprise!
... blue'''
>>> a
'red\nyellow\ngreen\n_surprise!\nblue'
```

Either:

```
>>> [x.replace("###", "\n_") for x in a.replace("\n_", "###").split()]
['red', 'yellow', 'green\n_surprise!', 'blue']
```

Or:

```
>>> [x.replace("###", "\n_") for x in a.replace("\n_", "###").splitlines()]
['red', 'yellow', 'green\n_surprise!', 'blue']
```

Comment: This answer will work, but is not as concise as @Haifeng Zhang's answer. Also if for example a was input form the user, if someone was trying to break the code they could by typing '###'. Thanks for the answer though!